# Why does newid() materialize at the very end of a query?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

If you run the following sample code in SQL Server, you'll notice that newid() materializes after the join whereas row_number() materializes before the join.  Does anyone understand this and if there's a way to work around it?

```
declare @a table ( num varchar(10) )
 insert into @a values ('dan')
 insert into @a values ('dan')
 insert into @a values ('fran')
 insert into @a values ('fran')

 select *
   from @a T
            inner join
        (select num, newid() id
           from @a
          group by num) T1      on T1.num = T.num         

 select *
   from @a T
            inner join
        (select num, row_number() over (order by num) id
           from @a
          group by num) T1      on T1.num = T.num
```

Comment: @pst: That's because it's "anonymous." :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I see what the problem is here. Materialize the subquery T1 first:

```
SELECT num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num) 
    FROM @a
    GROUP BY num;
```

You get two rows:

```
dan  1
fran 2
```

Now join that against a on num = num, you get 4 rows, 2 for each distinct value. What is your actual goal here? Perhaps you should be applying ROW_NUMBER() outside?

The order of materialization is up to the optimizer. You'll find that other built-ins (RAND(), GETDATE() etc.) have similarly inconsistent materialization behavior. Not much you can do about it, and not much chance they're going to "fix" it.

**EDIT**

New code sample. Write the contents of @a to a #temp table to "materialize" the NEWID() assignment per unique num value.

```
SELECT num, id = NEWID() 
  INTO #foo FROM @a GROUP BY num;

SELECT a.num, f.id 
  FROM @a AS a 
  INNER JOIN #foo AS f 
  ON a.num = f.num;

DROP TABLE #foo;
```

Comment: That's how it works for `row_number()`, but look at how it works for `newid()`.  Basically, what would you have to write to get `newid()` to work like `row_number()`?

Comment: I don't know that you can, it seems that NEWID() is materialized no matter where it is in the query. Why don't you create a GUID when you insert the row, and prevent duplicates? The only way to really materialize NEWID() for distinct num values is to write them down first. I'll add a second code sample.

Comment: yeah, temp tables are inefficient in my case unfortunately.  So it's bizarre but I don't think this has a solution.  I'll accept yours since you're probably right, this is the closest we'll get.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem and found out that the "inner join" was the problem. i was able to use "left joins" ...

Comment: Could you post two statements that would prove your assertion?  If I'm right, you're saying left joinining would make newid() materialize sooner?  That doesn't quite sound right.  Unfortunately too, a left join is not an option here.